# How to properly export a jar for running an applet?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jar, applet

I have been adding modifications to a Java application that runs on a server using an applet. On the server, there is just the jar file, and an index.html page that opens the applet.

Now, I am trying to test the new version of the app on my computer before putting it on the production server, and it doesn't work : the application doesn't connect with the MySQL DB (when I just run it from Eclipse it works, it is when I try to run the jar file from my browser that it doesn't work). I tried running the old app on my desktop the same way and it runs just fine, so I guess the problem is in my jar file.

I have opened the 2 jar archives to see what's inside, and here's what I get :

> Old jar :
>   Different folders for the different packages of the app
>   bin folder
>   com folder
>   META-INF folder
>   org folder
>   .classpath file
>   .project file
>   java.policy.applet file
>   mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar

And now, here is what's inside the new jar :

> Different folders for the different packages of the app
>   META-INF folder
>   .classpath file
>   .fatjar file
>   .project file
>   java.policy.applet file
>   mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar
>   settings.fatjar file

So my archive doesn't have the bin, com and org folders. It also has 2 additionnal files.

I don't know which settings should I use when exporting my jar in Eclipse to obtain the same content ?

Also, my new jar isn't signed, could this have something to do with my problem of database access ?

Comment: 1) Java class loaders are not intended (or designed) to deal with 'jar within a jar'. 2) Applets are subject to a security level that is different to Eclipse (no security, last time I checked) or the 'old app' (if a standard desktop app). 3) Applet jars need to be digitally signed. 4) Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, as I found the solution :

The jar needs to be exported as a runnable jar
The option "extract required libraries into jar" must be selected
The jar must be signed (self signed works as it is an internal app, so no need to pay a certificate)

Now it works :)